# how to send a email using office 365 api in c#.net?

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

how to send a email using office 365 API in c#.net?can anyone provide a sample code. I tried with Office 365 Exchange Web serivce and its worked.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you necessarily want to use a .NET SDK ? What's wrong with forging your own REST request https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Sendmessages. Why do you mention EWS? If it works why using Office 365 REST APIs or GRAPH API?

Comment: In my application I want to send some information on run time via email to client using office 365 api. I have only my office 365 account information.I don't have admin privileges(eg ) tenant id) . I am using c#.net  in my application.I want to send this by c#.net code

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear if you are looking for samples using SDK or raw HTTP requests.
Samples for sending mail using raw HTTP requests in C# are [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-UWP-Microsoft-Graph-Connect) and [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-AspNetMVC-Microsoft-Graph-Connect/tree/master/UnifiedApiConnect). Below is sample code snippet to send mail using the [sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph):

```
        GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(<UseYourAuthProvider>);
        Message message = new Message
        {
            Subject="Hello",
            Body=new ItemBody{Content="World",ContentType=BodyType.Text},
            ToRecipients=new []{new Recipient{EmailAddress=new EmailAddress{Address="john@contoso.com"}}}

        };
        var request = client.Me.SendMail(message, true);
        await request.Request().PostAsync();
```

A complete sample using the sdk is available [here](https://github.com/Mimetis/NextMeetingsForGraphSample) (Note: it is not related to sending mail, but should give you reference to sdk usage in general)

Comment: I am using vs 2013 so i cant open these examples.can you give an idea about <UseYourAuthProvider> or any code samples?

Comment: The reference in my response above for a complete sample using the sdk has an implementation of IAuthenticationProvider. Here is the link again - https://github.com/Mimetis/NextMeetingsForGraphSample